# How to scrape likes on instagram

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, instagram

I got a code to scrape instagram data. It's  scrape the followers, following, and posts, but i still need to scrape likes on post. Is there a way to scrape likes without API from instagram?

Here's the code for scrape, i still need to scrape likes on here.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

class Insta_Info_Scraper:

    def getinfo(self, url):
        html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=self.ctx).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        data = soup.find_all('meta', attrs={'property': 'og:description'
                             })
        text = data[0].get('content').split()
        user = '%s %s %s' % (text[-3], text[-2], text[-1])
        followers = text[0]
        following = text[2]
        posts = text[4]
        info={}
        info["User"] = user
        info["Followers"] = followers
        info["Following"] = following
        info["Posts"] = posts
        self.info_arr.append(info)
```

Comment: can you provide any example url?

Answer (score 4):

Given the hypothesis that you already collected some posts url, you could easily get the likes by doing the following:

```
posts = ['BxuiTcLnTWO','BxkKDnCngp0','BxiNq5-nxOj','Bxhr01unQ11']

for post in posts:
    post_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/{}/'.format(post)
    response = requests.get(post_url.format(post))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
    sharedData = soup.find('script', text=re.compile('"mainEntityofPage"')).text
    likes = json.loads(sharedData.strip())['interactionStatistic']['userInteractionCount']
    print(post_url, '-', likes, 'likes')
```

Output :

> https://www.instagram.com/p/BxuiTcLnTWO/ - 2243387 likes
>
> https://www.instagram.com/p/BxkKDnCngp0/ - 6278351 likes
>
> https://www.instagram.com/p/BxiNq5-nxOj/ - 1445806 likes
>
> https://www.instagram.com/p/Bxhr01unQ11/ - 1250237 likes

Answer (score 0):

You can use [instascrape](https://github.com/chris-greening/instascrape) to acquire this data with minimal code (disclaimer: I am the author of this library)

pip install using `pip install insta-scrape` and then

```py
from instascrape import Post 
google_post = Post("https://www.instagram.com/p/CG0UU3ylXnv/")
google_post.load()
print(f"{google_post.likes} likes")
>>> "37210 likes"
```